# How to detect wake up from sleep mode in windows service?

Tags: c++, winapi

Good day! I write a windows service, which detects USB Flash drive connection and do something with connected drive. And now after tests i need to reprocess devices after wake up from sleep mode. I solve this problem when service work as windows program. To solve i additionally process `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED`, but service don't receive this message, it receives only `DBT_DEVICE_ARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`. I also tried to check all messages handled by service except  `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` when system is going to sleep and i don't get any message.

How can I determine when the system is waking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to detect that system is waking up is process power messages.
Windows must process `WM_POWERBROADCAST`
Services must add `SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT` to last call to `SetServiceStatus` and process `SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT`

My error was very stupid. I forget to add `SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT`.

Answer (score 5):

A normal application receives a `WM_POWERBROADCAST:PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC` window message, but a service will not get this message if it does not have a window. However, a service can receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT` in its [`HandlerEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx) callback function, with the same parameters as `WM_POWERBROADCAST`

> Notifies a service of system power events. The dwEventType parameter contains additional information. If dwEventType is PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE, the lpEventData parameter also contains additional information.

On Windows 8 and later, you can also use the [`PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769080(v=vs.85).aspx) function:

> Registers to receive notification when the system is suspended or resumed.

The service equivalent of `WM_DEVICECHANGE` is `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT`:

> Notifies a service of device events. (The service must have registered to receive these notifications using the [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) function.) The dwEventType and lpEventData parameters contain additional information.

Comment: Thank you, i process `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT`. I will do more test at monday, but i don't get `SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVETN` and don't know why..

Comment: You a right, but and i and you forget one little thing. It is necessary add `SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWERBROADCAST` to call SetServiceStatus

Comment: Hi @Anders,
My windows service target version is Windows Xp. Is there any alternate way to detect wake up from sleep?

Comment: @ArjunNatarajan Does SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT not work?

Comment: Hi @Anders, my service is able to capture the SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT but I particularly need to detect system resume state. The lpEventData in the service handler method can hold the POWERBROADCAST_SETTING structure unfortunately, the min.supported client is Windows Vista [desktop apps only] which I can't able to use it in mine. 
Any other alternative solutions would be very helpful.

Comment: @ArjunNatarajan https://groups.google.com/d/topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/e5wavgDV2l0# claims that it reports the exact same wParams as WM_POWERBROADCAST.