# What happens with a Timer when the computer gets in sleep mode?

Tags: c#, service, sleep-mode, system.timers.timer

For example, I have a Windows service with a System.Timers.Timer function in it. The Timer does something every 3 hours. What if the computer running this service goes into sleep mode and what happens after waking up?

I assume the Timer stops when the computer goes to sleep and starts counting from zero after waking up. Is this right?

Comment: Why not run a test of your own with a timer < 3 hours?

Comment: May be related, but if you care about what happens specifically when the system wakes up [How to detect wake up from sleep mode in windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47942716/327083)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to timer in standby mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821745/what-happens-to-timer-in-standby-mode)